# (asp.net) Preserving some session variable in SQL Server after session time out possible?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session

I am new to asp.net. So please help me out. I am trying to preserve some session variable by changing the session mode to SQLServer using instruction on this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akshayns/archive/2008/10/04/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-a-session-state.aspx

I have read some posts saying that storing session in SQL Server database will preserve the session even after session time out. But in my case, after session time out, the session in aspstateTempSessions table is deleted as well. Is there a way I can tell asp.net to keep some session variables that I want to preserve after time out?

Thanks.

Comment: If variable needs to survive session end, why put it in the session ?

Comment: Thanks. That's very good question. The reason that I put it in the session because of two reasons. First, as I have read some articles, it is secure and second I do not have to apply any other procedures to  retrieve or remove it. Perhaps I have done it all wrong. Any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Store it to database, it's also secure :) If this process of getting this variable or data is slow use Cache (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Session is a volatile storage system, designed to only live as long as the session is active. If you need values to survive the session, you should go ahead and store them in a separate persistent structure, such as a SQL table that is tied to the user (not the session).

**Edit:**
If you can come up with an object structure to store the "state" of the wizard (steps completed, options selected, etc.), you could serialize the objects and store them as an XML BLOB in SQL Server, with the user's login and ProductID as the primary keys. That way you can deserialize the state and the user can resume from where they left off.

As I stated in the comments, you'll want to setup an abandonment timeout period, after which all edits for that object are deleted and considered lost.

Comment: Based on the answer, I feel that maybe it is not possible to achieve what I am trying to do using session. Here is my scenario: User1 lists a product called Product1. User1 can edit his own product1. However, because I stored the product1 ID in the session, if user1 is in the 3rd step of editing and he leaves the computer idle for 20 mns, the session will time out. When he comes back and log in, he has to start from 1st step because the product1 ID is lost. I just want him to continue from where he left. What state management is best in this case? Thanks.

Comment: I see. As I stated, if you want something to survive the session, you should store it separately and tie it to the user, not the session. You can always clean out the "steps completed" after the user clicks Finish successfully, or after a sufficient number of days to consider it abandoned.